# Jasmine pre-commit hook to check for excluded/focused tests

Tags: javascript, angular, jasmine, git-husky

During development I often exclude/focus tests. I want to make sure that those tests are not commited.

Every occurence of `xdescribe`, `fdescribe`, `xit` or `fit` should trigger an error with the file and line number where it occurred.

Is there a library for this? If not, how would a custom script look like?

Setup:

- husky 1.1.4
- jasmine 2.8.0
- karma 3.0.0

Edit:
I'm not running the tests with pre-commit hooks. I'm worried that someone accidentally checks-in tests with `xdescribe`, `fdescribe`, `xit` or `fit` and not all our tests are executed on the build-server.

Comment: we run headless Chrome

Comment: you'd possibly need something alike https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node in order to get log-files, which can be parsed - in order to understand if a test failed; then act accordingly.